# Using Kotlin code in a Java Android Application

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to integrate a code of an SDK written in Kotlin which consists of some imports and some methods like onCreate(), onIntent() etc. in my Android application written in Java which also has the same methods (I want to merge those same methods). However, my application has lots of Java classes, and the Kotlin code is needed only in one class. When I convert that class to Kotlin, it becomes so difficult to handle all errors generated from different Java classes, so I don't want to convert that Java class to Kotlin.

So, how can I solve this issue? Should I convert the Kotlin code to Java or is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is that class `final`? You can always keep what you need in Java class and extend it in Kotlin.

Comment: No, it is not final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert Kotlin into Java or vice versa. You can work with both languages in a single project.

Since you are working on an Android project, then both Kotlin and Java are compiled into JVM bytecode. For that reason, you can call Kotlin classes into Java and the opposite.

I would suggest to have a look [Kotlin - Java interoperability guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html).

Comment: What about the same methods in both classes? How can I merge two same methods?

Comment: You can use inheritance in order to integrate logic. 
Merging big methods together seems like a bad coding practice anyways (cause methods should be short to be readable). 
You could also call same methods manually.